# Comparing strings in C++ that have the same letters but in different order

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to programming. I need to compare two strings which have the exact same elements but in different order. I have tried using `strcmpi()` to compare but it does not work. I tried using `is_permutation()` which I read on the net, is used to compare strings with same elements, but my compiler is saying it does not exist even though I included `<algorith.h>`. My compiler is Borland C++. Is there any other way to compare 2 strings and get them evaluated as equal with the same elements but arranged in different order?
For example `"evil"` and `"vile"`.

Comment: `std::sort` and then compare.

Comment: You can sort the characters in each string.

Comment: `<algorith.h>` is not a standard header, and nor is `<algorithm.h>`. A [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) on the C++ headers would tell you as much. Anyway, I don't know if Borland even supports the algorithms, but you'll basically have to reinvent `std::is_permutation` in some form (even if it is more inefficient) if not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using Borland C++? Didn't that die about a decade ago?

Comment: If your strings are composed of single byte (narrow) characters and you are not concerned with character duplications, you can use a bitmasking technique.  The index into the bitmask would be the binary character value.  You will have to master bitwise and shift operations though.

Comment: *my compiler is borland c++* -- Get an up-to-date compiler, not something from 20 years ago.

Comment: Actually, a new version of the old C++ compiler was recently released: [A new edition of our free C++ compiler](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-new-edition-of-our-free-c-compiler)

Comment: I'm still in school and they use this compiler. I simply borrowed it from them. Don't know why they still use it though.

Comment: @james Get the latest version at the link Remy gave.  The command-line is still the same, and you get to use C++ as it stands today, not 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will get it

Answer (score 2):

1. Your compiler is *old*. I did not check, but I'm fairly certain it does not support C++11 which is required for [std::is_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation).
2. As comments have already pointed out, you can just `sort` the strings and then compare them.
3. As also pointed out in the comments, the headers you try to include are non-standard/not correct (again probably due to you using an ancient compiler - get a modern one already; both VS2015, GCC 6.1 and Clang 3.8 can be had for free and all offer quite good C++11/C++14 support).

Comment: VS2015 is far from free.

Comment: The community edition is free for personal use.

Comment: "Free for personal use" != "Free". I would expect most of the users of stackoverflow are not personal programmers.

Comment: Fine. Let's call it non-free then. But I believe it's actually also free for commercial use as long as your business makes less than $1million/year (but I didn't bother to double-check). In any case, *a* free, modern, C++14 compliant compiler *can* be obtained for free with minimal effort. There's *no* reason to keep using a decades old compiler.

Comment: The latest [free version of Embarcadero's C++ compiler](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-new-edition-of-our-free-c-compiler) was just released last week and supports C++11.

Comment: Ohh. I had no idea they kept developing that compiler. I thought it died 20 years ago.

Comment: I'm still in school and my school for some reason still uses this compiler

Answer (score 2):

You can count how many times each character appears on each string, if they're equal then return true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool anagrams(string s, string t){

    if(s.length() != t.length())
        return false;

    int chArr[256];
    // Set character's count to 0
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
        chArr[i] = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        chArr[s[i]]++;
        chArr[t[i]]--;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
        if(chArr[i] != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(){
    if(anagrams("hello, olelh"))
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is the one I prefer, but it does require more space than Nathan Oliver's solution. I would recommend updating your answer to use an std::unordered_map.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan Oliver suggests, sort the two and then check if they are equal. The source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool AreAnagrams(string s1, string s2) {
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    sort(s2.begin(), s2.end());
    return s1 == s2;
}

int main() {
    if (AreAnagrams("evil", "vile"))
        cout << "Are anagrams." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Are not anagrams." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out